# Integrating Wink and Spring in Tomcat

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, apache-wink, apache-wink-spring

I am attempting to access a Wink Resource that should be deployed in tomcat.  The Resource code is

```
@Path("/lookup")
public class LookupResource {

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LookupResource.class);

private MetaService metaService;

/**
 * 
 */
public LookupResource() {
    logger.debug("CTOR +-");
}

/**
 * @return the metaService
 */
public MetaService getMetaService() {
    return metaService;
}

/**
 * @param metaService the metaService to set
 */
public void setMetaService(MetaService metaService) {
    logger.debug(String.format("Setting Meta Svc: %s ", metaService));
    this.metaService = metaService;
}

    @GET
@Path("/states")
@Produces("application/json")
public JSONObject getStates() {
        final String METHOD = "getMessage";
        JSONObject answer = new JSONObject();
        try {
          logger.debug(String.format("%s +", METHOD));
          List<Lookup> states = getMetaService().findStates();
          for (Lookup state : states) {
              answer.put("Lookup", state);
          }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
          logger.debug("Problem", e);
        } finally {
          logger.debug(String.format("%s -", METHOD));
        }
        return answer;

}
    }
```

I added Spring to the web.xml

```
    <context-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>classpath:META-INF/server/wink-core-context.xml
                   classpath:my-server.xml
                   classpath:my-webapp.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
      <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
```

And in my-webapp.xml spring configuration I registered the Resource

```
<bean id="lookupResource" class="com.codeheadllc.webapp.LookupResource" >
  <property name="metaService" ref="metaService" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.apache.wink.spring.Registrar">
  <property name = "instances">
    <set>
      <ref bean="lookupResource"/>
    </set>
  </property>
</bean>
```

When I deploy and start tomcat I see in the logger that my LookupResource bean is loaded and it gets a reference to the metaService.  However, when I hit http:///my-webapp/lookup/states, instead of accessing LookupResouce, I get a 404 message.  I am sure it is a bonehead oversight, but I do not understand what I am doing wrong.  If I add a servlet to the web.xml for RestServlet and add a mapping, say rest/*, then the RestServlet will create a new instance of LookupResource (without spring IOC) and attempt to execute the method.

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

> If I add a servlet to the web.xml for RestServlet and add a mapping, say rest/*, then the RestServlet will create a new instance of LookupResource (without spring IOC) and attempt to execute the method.

Hey! You still need to add the servlet to web.xml !

Spring integration does NOT replaces the RestServlet. It only allows defining the resources as Spring beans.